# Warning Illegal string offset in PHP Error from Printing Items in an Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an PHP array named $link that contains this -

```
Array
(
    [title] => View Guides
    [url] => https://siteurl.com/guides/
    [target] => 
)
```

and I am trying to insert these array items into HTML like this -

```
<a href="<?php echo $link['url'] ?>"<?php echo $link['target'] === '_blank' ? ' target="_blank"' : '' ?>><?php echo $link['title'] ?></a>
```

I get a "Uncaught Error: Cannot access offset of type string on string" error. On PHP 7 this is a warning, but on PHP 8 it is a fatal error.

What is wrong with the syntax I am using to try and print these array items?

Edit -

I did a `var_dump()` on `$link` and this was the result -

```
array(3) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(9) "View Guides"
  ["url"]=>
  string(22) "https://siteurl.com/guides/"
  ["target"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

So it appears the items are strings. Is there different syntax I need to use?

Comment: It appears that `$link` isn't an array, but a string.  I suggest you do a `var_dump($link)` to inspect it further.

Comment: Is it `$links` or `$link`? The question states `$links` but the code states `$link`, and there is no indication of a loop

Comment: My mistake it is link, I edited the post

Comment: @RobEyre I edited the post with the results from the ```var_dump()```

Comment: @jfc Was that var_dump placed _directly before_ the `a` element you are creating in your code? If not, it's possible that something between the var_dump and the `a` element is changing the contents of `$link`

Comment: Please add code showing `var_dump` addition. Also is `target` always set or only if `blank`? Doesnt reproduce here https://3v4l.org/4pqJ8

Answer (score 0):

I think that a plausible scenario is that sometimes $link is a string instead of an array.
You should try to find where and when this happens.

Or you can try to use null coalescing operator in combination with Elvis operator to work around the problem, like so:

```
<a href="<?= ($link['url'] ?? $link) ?: '#' ?>" <?= ($link['target'] ?? '') === '_blank' ? ' target="_blank"' : '' ?>> <?= $link['title'] ?? '_LINK_' ?></a>
```